# Finding range of an algebraic fraction

Tags: functions

How to find range of the function $f(x)=\frac{2x^4-14x^2-8x+49}{x^4-7x^2-4x+23}$ ?
The question seems simple but I can't figure it out!

Comment: Keeping in mind that we cannot divide by zero, where is the function not defined?

Comment: Hint: your life gets a lot easier if you notice that the numerator looks a lot like twice the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the question doesn't seem that simple.

Anyway, there is a big simplification by observing that
$$\frac{2x^4-14x^2-8x+49}{x^4-7x^2-4x+23}=2+\frac3{x^4-7x^2-4x+23},$$
and the problem reduces to the study the polynomial at the denominator.

Let us find its extrema, by

$$4x^3-14x-4=0,$$

that has the root $x=2$ by inspection.

Then by long division, we factor as

$$2(x-2)(2x^2+4x+1)=0$$

and the other roots are

$$x=-1\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}.$$

As the second derivative $12x^2-14$ is positive for $x=2$, we have two minima, at $x=2$ and $x=-1-\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Then, $P(2)=3$, and $P(-1-\frac1{\sqrt2})>P(2)$, so that the minimum value is $3$ and there are no real roots.

Hence, the range of the function is $(2+\frac1\infty,2+\frac33]=(2,3]$.